How to configure dynamically generated redirect urls in AAD for preview environments?
Hello,
Im using Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1 to deploy a static website to Azure.
The site is configured to be only accessable for accounts in our organization with a custom domain.
So far everything works fine.
I want to use preview environments for pull requests in GitHub.
In every pull request a new preview environment is created and the url for that environment is dynamically generated.
They always look somthing like this: https://random-name-{PRID}.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net
Navigating to that url correctly returns an error:
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://my-random-page-3.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.

Manually adding the generated URL to redirect URLs in the Azure Application works fine.

How can I automate that configuration, so that every generated preview environment is protected and can be accessed by anyone in our organization?
By completing the pull request the url should also be removed from the configuration.
Thank you for your Help!

You can update the redirect URL as https://*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net using az cli

Make use of this command az ad app update --id AppID --add replyUrls "https://*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"

Thank you for your answers.
replyUrls did not work, but I tried it using az ad app update --id  AppID --web-redirect-uris "https://uri1.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
That worked fine.
Sadly it does not work using wildcards like you suggested.
Invalid value specified for property 'web' of resource 'Application'.

Check the below answer

Since your redirect URL is https://my-random-page-3.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback and the pull request ID is dynamic you can make use of * wildcard to set the redirect URL.

Set *  wildcard to make the redirect URL accept the dynamic pull requests.
You can set the redirect URL as https://*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback.

To set a dynamic redirect URL in Azure AD, use the below CLI command:
az login

az ad app update --id ApplicationID --add replyUrls "https://*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback" --only-show-errors


Redirect URL updated in the Azure Portal successfully:


Thank you for your answer.
I used a slightly different command, but that worked.
az ad app update --id AppId --web-redirect-uris "https://*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
That solution works. But isn´t that a potential security problem?
I also tried to include the random generated name and only replace the PR id by the wildcard, but that is not a valid value for the redirect URL.
https://random-name-*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris

Redirect URL in this form https://random-name-*.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/aad/callback is not valid

I have given the workaround to work with dynamic redirect URLs and yes it causes security issues and this is only way to work with dynamic redirect URL AFAIK

Great that I could help:)
